# Deserializing a boolean value with nullable attribute?

Tags: c#, rest, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I am deserializing a string back to an object using C#. The xml string looks like

```
"<Authentication xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
  <Status>Success</Status>
  <Available i:nil=\"true\"/>
</Authentication>"
```

While I'm managed to handle the Available by making the bool property nullable, I'm just wondering what is the correct way to handle i:nil=\"true\"?

Should I being doing something else other than just making a property Available property nullable?

Note that without making the bool property nullable, it throws me an error i.e. string "" cannot be converted to bool, so making nullable sorted my problem, but I'm just curious as to whether or not I should be doing more than just making this nullable

Thanks.

Comment: I think your property _should_ be nullable. The XML schema is pretty much explicitly telling you that the property can be `true`, `false`, _or_ `null`. IIRC, this will deserialize fine, but if you tried to serialize it, you won't get the same XML. You should double-check, but I _think_ if you adorn your class property with `[XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]` it should make it so it outputs the `i:nil="true"` attribute when you have a `null` value. EDIT: Nevermind, I just did a test, you don't need the element `IsNullable` to be defined. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property *should* be nullable. The XML is explicitly telling you that the property can be either `true`, `false`, or `null`; the 3 are valid values and your class should support all 3.

You don't need to do anything other than making your property a `bool?`; the `XmlSerializer` will properly handle reading/writing the `i:nil="true"` when the property is `null`.

Just make sure that your code is designed to account for the `null` values where applicable so you don't get exceptions.